# Include some headers with form submission

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Using AngleSharp, I'm trying to load a page and then do a form submission, but it isn't giving me the expected result (i.e. not the same as the browser) and I think it might be because of some missing headers. What's the best place to hook in and add some headers when you submit a form? Can I get hold of the request before it is sent?

For example, my code looks something like:

```
var doc = currentContext.OpenAsync(baseUrl).Result;
var form = doc.QuerySelector("form") as IHtmlFormElement;
// do some stuff to manipulate the form
// ...
// Here I need to set a header before SubmitAsync...
doc = form.SubmitAsync().Result;
```

Answer (score 2):

I could not find how to hook header settings into a `BrowsingContext` instance's request.

In case no one else finds how to do it using `AngleSharp` only, which should be the preferred solution, one workaround would be to issue the http request yourself, *manually*, using the framework's `HttpClient`, so you can play with the request headers as you wish, and then extract the response's text and pass it to `AngleSharp`'s `HtmlParser`, something I usually do.

Example:

```
    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("headerSetting", "headerValue");
    var response = await hc.GetAsync("yourUrl");

    var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    //from here on you are under AngleSharp's jurisdiction...
    var parser = new HtmlParser();
    IHtmlDocument parsedDoc = parser.Parse(html);
```

If you are not sure of which `headers` you may be missing in your code-made `http request`, one thing I usually do to analyze a post request and make sure I am not missing any `headers`, is to do the action in the browser while an instance of `Fiddler` is running, so I can *dissect* it.

For example, say you have a form like

[image]

Using fiddler I can see everything that was send to the server (including cookies)

[image]

And `headers`, which is what you are after. Here you will be able to know all the `header` settings that are sent doing the action via browser, so you can mimic it in your code-made `http request` (you have all the data for both `request` and `response`).

[image]

Comment: That's a nice answer to the question _"How do I inspect an HTTP request"_, which this question doesn't seem to be.

Comment: You are actually right. I forgot to add the hooking places he asks for - the Headers collection from the HttpClient. He's using AngleSharp, however, I am not sure I know where to hook there, will take a look. Why is it that your username rings me a (1 ? lots of) bell ? :)

Comment: It's probably because I go around and criticise other people's answers when I feel like it. It's not the first time we meet indeed.

Comment: Mine was a witty remark. I definitely remember you *picking* my actions here at SO :). But without a doubt, here you were absolutely right :)